# Regular expressions, capture groups, and the dollar sign

Tags: bash, perl, rename, pcre

Reading a book about bash and it was introducing regular expressions(I'm pretty new to them) with an example:

```
rename -n 's/(.*)(.*)/new$1$2/' *

'file1' would be renamed to 'newfile1'
'file2' would be renamed to 'newfile2'
'file3' would be renamed to 'newfile3'
```

There wasn't really a breakdown provided with this example, unfortunately. I kind of get what capture groups are and that .* is greedy and will match all characters but I'm uncertain as to why two capture groups are needed. Also, I get that $ represents the end of the line but am unsure of what $1$2 is actually doing here. Appreciate any insight provided.

Attempted to research capture groups and the $ for some similar examples with explanations but came up short.

Comment: It's important to realize that this regular expression will be processed by the `rename` command, not by bash itself, and it may ll have somewhat different syntax from bash regular expressions (most obviously, bash doesn't put its capture groups in `$1`, `$2`, etc, but in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` etc. And `grep` and `sed` and `awk` etc all do things a little differently..

Comment: @Felthorn3 - What book is this?

Comment: @JimDavis it's "Learn Bash the Hard Way" by Ian Miell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. `(.*)(.*)` makes no sense. The second `.*` will always match the empty string.

For example, matching against `file`,

- the first `.*` will match the 4 character string starting at position 0 (`file`), and
- the second `.*` will match the 0 character string starting at position 4 (empty string).

You could simplify the pattern to

```bash
rename -n 's/(.*)/new$1/' *
```

```bash
rename -n 's/.*/new$&/' *
```

```bash
rename -n 's/^/new/' *
```

```bash
rename -n '$_ = "new$_"' *
```

```bash
rename -n '$_ = "new" . $_' *
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it really helped clarify and that I wasn't completely crazy!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that `rename` command. The regular expression looks like `sed` syntax. If that is the case (as in many other regex forms), it has 3 parts:

- `s` for substitute
- everything between the first two slashes `(.*)(.*)` to specify what to match
- everything between the 2nd and 3rd slash `new$1$2` is the replacement

`$` only mean end of the line on the first part of the regular expression. On the second part `$` number refers to the capture groups, `$1` is the first group, `$2` the second, and so on, with `$0` often being the whole matched text.

You are right that `.*` is greedy and it's pointless to have that repeated. Maybe there was a `\.` in between and that was an attempt to capture file name and extension. There are better ways to parse file names, like `basename`. So you could simplify the command to `rename -n 's/(.*)/new$1/' *`

Comment: It's probably this [rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/rename) script; it's Perl.

Comment: Indeed. It's not a regular expression but a Perl statement. In this instance, it's a substitute operator (which it's a regex pattern, but does include one.).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I'm glad I'm not completely crazy!